# Ruby converting an array to a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have the following string and I would like to convert it to a hash printing the below result

```
string = "Cow, Bill, Phone, Flour"

hash = string.split(",")

>> {:animal => "Cow", :person: "Bill", :gadget => "Phone", 
    :grocery => "Flour"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash = Hash[[:animal, :person, :gadget, :grocery].zip(string.split(/,\s*/))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max but that actually 

    prints {:animal=>"Cow, Bill, Phone, Flour", :person=>nil, :gadget=>nil, :grocery=>nil}

Comment: Judging by the edit of your comment, I don't think you actually looked at what my code was doing. My code definitely worked (I tested it before posting the answer) but I've updated it to split more generically as well.

Comment: my apologies...I had an extra variable in my string

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Max is quite nice.  You might understand it better as:

```
def string_to_hash(str)
  values = str.split(/,\s*/)
  names = [:animal, :person, :gadget, :grocery]
  Hash[names.zip(values)]
end
```

Here is a less sophisticated approach:

```
def string_to_hash(str)
  parts = str.split(/,\s*/)
  Hash[
    :animal  => parts[0],
    :person  => parts[1],
    :gadget  => parts[2],
    :grocery => parts[3],
  ]
end
```